# What is the Unity teachings of Jesus' resurrection?

Tags: resurrection-of-jesus

The [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_Church) church is unorthodox, however I was wondering what the exact teachings were of Jesus' resurrection.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: "Unity describes itself as having no particular creed, no set dogma ..." This makes me doubtful whether it has any particular teachings on Jesus' resurrection.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Matt, I too read the article that I linked.  I was hoping for some practical experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Wikipedia article mentions that there are no creeds or dogma w/in Unity, I have found by practical experience that this is not the case (by attending a service).

A list of creeds may be found on any of the church's sites, such as Unity Hills:

> Jesus Christ - Jesus is a master teacher of universal truths and the
>   Way-Shower in Unity teachings. "Unity teaches that the spirit of God
>   lived in Jesus, just as it lives in every person." Jesus expressed his
>   divine potential and showed others how to express their divinity,
>   which Unity calls Christ. Unity does not refer to Jesus as God, Son of
>   God, Savior, or Messiah.

Further more per [www.bible.ca](http://www.bible.ca/cr-Unity.htm):

> Unity rejects the traditional Christian view that Jesus is a deity to
>   be worshiped; we point out that at no time did Jesus tell his
>   disciples to worship him. Rather, we look upon Jesus as a great
>   healer, miracle worker, and mystic who had a direct access to God. We
>   believe that his actions can be emulated by believers today. One's
>   life is to be dominated by love, and compassion, even toward one's
>   enemies.

Unity does not directly address the resurrection of Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

The mindset of Unity seems to be that it's not important whether Jesus physically resurrected or not. Just as a lot of Christians don't really care whether Jesus spoke of an actual beggar named Lazarus or simply made up a parable, Unity regards Jesus' victory over death as an example for us and having no other benefit, therefore they don't care about the details.

A Unity minister [says](http://www.unitychristchurch.org/q-does-unity-believe-in-the-physical-death-and-resurrection-of-jesus/):

> In today’s Unity there would be a range of answers, But, most Unity
>   ministers teach to look beyond the event for the lessons in your life.
>   To see beyond the physical facts of the story and see the underlying
>   message for you.

He does mention that Charles Fillmore, considered the founder of Unity, almost certainly did believe in Jesus' literal resurrection. The minister claims "Jesus death did not save us from our sin but pointed the way to the truth."